# How to create a generic function that composes methods to parse config data?

Tags: c#, generics, configuration

I have config with several properties that has been injected via the Option Pattern i.e.

```
private readonly CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration;

public DataManager( IOptions<CacheConfiguration> cacheConfiguration )
{
    this.cacheConfiguration = cacheConfiguration;
}
```

The config values are initially strings, but will eventually be parsed to a type which can be `int`, `TimeSpan`, `double` etc.

Now I can parse values like so

```
private int A => int.Parse(this.cacheConfiguration.A);
private datetime B = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(this.cacheConfiguration.B));
private datetime C = TimeSpan.FromHours(int.Parse(this.cacheConfiguration.C));
private string D => this.cacheConfiguration.D;
...
```

but all 4 calls(and more) follow a pattern that seems reusable, which I'm trying to just encapsulate into a generic function (and learn more about generic functions in the process). So I got started with writing

```
public static T ParseAs<T> ( string configVal, Func<double, T> func ) => func (int.Parse(configVal));
```

My method seems to cover the case for B and C, but no case A and D where either only integer parsing is done and no parsing is done at all, respectively. Is there a way to fix my method such that it can compose functions to:

- parse string to int only
- parse string to double to timespan
- no parsing (keep it string)
- other various compositions of parsing

Would what I'm doing be an overkill?

Comment: I don't see the value of such a function, as you have to pass it a function to specify what it has to do. But you cache the parsed values: `private int? _a; private int A => _a ??= int.Parse(this.cacheConfiguration.A);`

Comment: Is there any particular reason why `CacheConfiguration` can't have properties of correct type from the start?

Comment: `CacheConfiguration` is a class where each of the config values have their own property and getter and setter. It's bound to the values it has read from the config which are string. I don't think I can have any other type that's not string or boolean in there e.g. datetime